# Enter-PSsession won't run command get-aduser

Tags: powershell

So here's my issue.

A company we acquired uses a jump box. Which is a server that I need to access to be able to jump to other server.

So I'm running a script to enter the jumpbox, and then run get-aduser to access 3 other domains that are accessible by this server.

If i use mstsc to remote into the box, i can run the command:

`get-aduser -filter * -server firstdomain.com`

this runs fine, and gathers all the users. However, if i run a script that uses psremoting, and then try to run the command above - it returns an error stating that it cannot find the server. 
The commands look like this:

`enter-pssession -computer 10.0.2.70 -credential (get-credential)`

The command line changes to indicate that future commands are run through the server i've remoted into.

`[10.0.2.70]: PS C:\windows\system32> get-aduser -filter * -server firstdomain.com`

this returns the error stating that it cannot find the server. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issues with Invoke-Command while installing softwares in remote server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26677938/issues-with-invoke-command-while-installing-softwares-in-remote-server)

Comment: that's most likely the issue - PS doesn't like double hopping, and needs to delegate creds. thanks.